# Comparing with current time SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, time, model, compare

I'm trying to get a page to display a list of all the records that are valid at the current time, so comparing the start and end time & date to the time at that current moment. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
def self.time
find_by_sql("SELECT *
FROM screens s
WHERE (s.starttime < CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 114)) AND (s.finishtime > CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 114))")
end
```

However I get this: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`

I know my code isn't right.. I just don't quite know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.time
  find_by_sql("SELECT *
  FROM screens s
  WHERE (s.starttime < #{Time.now}) AND (s.finishtime >  #{Time.now}")
end
```

Comment: still says statement invalid `Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10:14:45 +0000) AND (s.finishtime >  2013-01-08 10:14:45 +0000' at line 3: SELECT *
  FROM screens s
  WHERE (s.starttime < 2013-01-08 10:14:45 +0000) AND (s.finishtime >  2013-01-08 10:14:45 +0000`

Comment: I think we will miss the single quote(') in the time. like this ' 2013-01-08 10:14:45 +0000'